# How to pass an argument to a button click function inside bootstrap popover content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of box objects and I am making each of them has a popover window. I add a button inside my popover window and I am trying to set the `click` event function for the button. The `click` function show invoke my `showBox(box)` function which takes an argument `box`. How can I pass this `box` argument to the button inside the popover window? Here is the code I have now:

```
var tabindex = 0;
box_resources.forEach(function(box) {
    var title = truncateTitle(box.title);
    var title_button = '<a tabindex="' + tabindex + '" class="box-title-item btn btn-primary btn-xs" role="button" data-trigger="focus" style="margin:5px" data-toggle="popover">' + title + '</a>';
    var $list_item = $(title_button);

    $("#coverages-master-list").append($list_item);

    var show_box_button = '<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button">' + box.title + '</a>';

    $list_item.popover({
        html: true,
        placement: 'top',
        title: box.title,
        content: '<p>' + show_box_button + '</p>',
        trigger: 'focus'
    });

    tabindex++;

});
```

How can I bind a `click` event for my `show_box_button` and how can I make it invoke my `showBox(box)` function which takes an argument `box`? Thanks!

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbfjkuxh/) link.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle or Codepen link?

Comment: @Carr Added the jsfiddle linke

Comment: There is a good answer ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the popover `.on('shown.bs.popover'...` event to add your click event to the current popover button

> make sure to use `.one('click'...` here not `.on('click'...`

and then call your `showBox` function with the `box_resources` array adding the `tabindex` of the current element.

```js
$(function () {

  var $coveragesMasterList = $("#coverages-master-list");

  var showBox = function(box) {
    console.log(box.title);
  }

  var box_resources = [
    { title: 'Box A' },
    { title: 'Box B' },
    { title: 'Box C' },
    { title: 'Box D' },
    { title: 'Box E' }
  ];

  var tabindex = 0;
  box_resources.forEach(function(box) {
    var title_button = '<a tabindex="' + tabindex + '" class="box-title-item btn btn-primary btn-xs" role="button" data-trigger="focus" style="margin:5px" data-toggle="popover">' + box.title + '</a>';

    var $list_item = $(title_button);

    $coveragesMasterList.append($list_item);

    var show_box_button = '<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button">' + box.title + '</a>';

    $list_item.popover({
      html: true,
      placement: 'top',
      title: box.title,
      content: '<p>' + show_box_button + '</p>',
      trigger: 'focus'
    });

    $list_item.on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
      var boxIndex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
      var $crntPopOver = $(this).next();
      var $crntPopOverBtn = $crntPopOver.find('.btn-default');
      $crntPopOverBtn.one('click', function() {
        showBox(box_resources[boxIndex]);
      })
    })

    tabindex++;
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="coverages-master-list" style="display:inline-block; height:150px; overflow-y: auto"></div>
```

Comment: Based on tests on my program, sometimes it does not invoke `showBox(box)` function immediately. I need to click it twice. Do you have any idea on it?

Comment: Did you change the `trigger: 'focus'` to `trigger: 'click'` ?

Comment: No, I am still using `focus`. Should I change it to `click`?

Comment: No, `focus` should be fine. Do have to click the button in the popover twice, or the tab button?

Comment: I think I might find the problem... I am passing `box` to `showBox` function. I  just changed the parameter to `box_resources[boxIndex]` as you have in code, and it seems it is working fine now. I am not quite sure what is the main difference here. Why does it cause this problem?

Comment: `box` is the current item in the iteration of the `forEach` loop, it might not be present in the callback function of the event handlers. I'm referencing the current index by the `tabindex` attribute of the element that triggers the `shown.bs.popover`, so you can easily access the item form the `box_resources` array by the index.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks!